# Script times out because I write data to a large sheet row by row. How can I optimize?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating my own stock tracker in Google Sheets. But because the `googlefinance()` function is not always reliable to return data, and because I don't want to make too many function calls, I am trying to retrieve and store historical stock data.

My sheet therefore has (among others) 3 sheets: `stockData`, `temp` and `log`. The `stochData` sheet looks as follows:

```
|   Date    | Ticker 1 | Ticker 2 | Ticker 3 |
|-----------|----------|----------|----------|
| 2000-01-01|   100.00 |   200.00 |   300.00 |
| 2001-03-02|   101.00 |   201.00 |   301.00 |
| 2002-03-06|   102.00 |   202.00 |   302.00 |
| 2003-01-01|   103.00 |   203.00 |   303.00 |
| 2004-01-01|   104.00 |   204.00 |   304.00 |
| 2005-01-01|   105.00 |   205.00 |   305.00 |
| 2006-01-01|   106.00 |   206.00 |   306.00 |
| ...       |   ...    |   ...    |   ...    |
| 2023-09-04|   108.00 |   208.00 |   308.00 |
| 2023-09-05|   NA     |   NA     |   NA     |
| 2023-09-06|   NA     |   NA     |   NA     |
| 2023-09-07|   NA     |   NA     |   NA     |
| 2023-09-08|   NA     |   NA     |   NA     |
| 2023-09-11|   NA     |   NA     |   NA     |
| 2023-09-12|   NA     |   NA     |   NA     |
| 2023-09-13|   NA     |   NA     |   NA     |
```

Notice that Column A is pre-filled with dates (in reality up to `2024-12-31`). The code below:

1. takes a stock ticker as argument and fetches the historical data up to today
2. writes the data to `temp`
3. creates a dictionary from `temp`
4. checks if there already is historical data in `stockData` for this ticker. If there is, we will overwrite the data. If there isn't, the data is written into the next available column
5. write the data from the dictionary to `stockData` by iterating through the dates in `stockDdata!$A2:A`, matching on the dates in the dictionary
6. Write some messages to the `log`

The problem is that this script is very inefficient and very frequently times out (after 6 minutes), because I am iterating row-by-row to match against the dictionary.

Can someone please help me optimize this code? There must be much more efficient ways for writing data to the sheet, but I really don't know how.

```
function fetchHistoricalPrices(ticker) 
{
  var originalTicker = ticker;
  ticker = _ticker(ticker); // format to be understood by Google

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("stockData");
  var tempSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("temp");
  var endDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  
  try {
    // Dates passed into GOOGLEFINANCE are treated as noon UTC time. Exchanges that close before that time may be shifted by a day.
    // Meaning, it could be that yesterdays closing prices only appear 24 hours after exchange close.
    tempSheet.getRange("A1").setFormula(
      '=QUERY(googlefinance("' + ticker + '", "close", "2000-01-01", "' + endDate + '"), ' +
      '"SELECT Col1, Col2 LABEL Col1 \'Date\', Col2 \'Price\' FORMAT Col1 \'DD.MM.YYYY\', Col2 \'0.00\'", 1)'
    );
    log("Data retrieval and writing to temp completed for ticker " + originalTicker + " from 2000-01-01 to " + endDate);

    // Get the last rows and ranges of dates and prices in the temp sheet (skip the first row)
    var lastRowTemp = tempSheet.getLastRow();
    var datesTemp   = tempSheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRowTemp - 1, 1).getValues();
    var pricesTemp  = tempSheet.getRange(2, 2, lastRowTemp - 1, 1).getValues();

    // Create an object (dictionary) to store dates and closing prices as key-value pairs
    var datePriceMap = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < datesTemp.length; i++) {
      //var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(datesTemp[i][0]), "UTC", "MM/dd/yyyy");
      var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(datesTemp[i][0]), "UTC", "dd.MM.yyyy");
      datePriceMap[formattedDate] = pricesTemp[i][0];
    }
    log("Dates and prices dictionary completed for ticker " + originalTicker);

    // Get the existing tickers from the first row of the "stockData" sheet
    var firstRow = [];
    if (sheet.getLastColumn() > 1) {
      firstRow = sheet.getRange(1, 2, 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - 1).getValues()[0];
    }

    // Get the values from the range in column A of the "stockData" sheet
    var datesStockData = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();

    // Find the next available empty column in the stockData sheet
    var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var tickerColumnIndex = lastColumn + 1; // Start from the next column after the last column

    // Get the existing ticker index in the "stockData" sheet
    var existingTickerIndex = firstRow.indexOf(originalTicker);

    if (existingTickerIndex !== -1) {
      tickerColumnIndex = existingTickerIndex + 2; // Adding 2 to account for 1-based index and skipping first column
    } else {
      // Write the ticker name as the header in the next empty column of the stockData sheet
      sheet.getRange(1, tickerColumnIndex).setValue(originalTicker);
    }

    // Iterate through the dates in column A and write prices to the corresponding cells
    for (var i = 0; i < datesStockData.length; i++) {
      //var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(datesStockData[i][0]), "UTC", "MM/dd/yyyy");
      var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(datesStockData[i][0]), "UTC", "dd.MM.yyyy");
      var price = datePriceMap[formattedDate] || "NA";
      var priceCell = sheet.getRange(i + 2, tickerColumnIndex); // Offset by 2 because we skipped the first row
      priceCell.setValue(price);
    }

    tempSheet.clear();
    log("Data written to stockData for ticker " + originalTicker);
  }
  catch (error) {
    log("Error fetching data for ticker " + originalTicker + ": " + error);
  }

  Utilities.sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: Write your results to a two dimensional array and then to the spreadsheet with setValues() all at one time.  Probably 10 x faster

Comment: Can you please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? Also, I'm trying to replicate and understand what is the expected return for `ticker = _ticker(ticker); // format to be understood by Google` ?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, I guessed the process cost of the following 2 parts.

  1. The process cost of the formula of `'=QUERY(googlefinance("' + ticker + '", "close", "2000-01-01", "' + endDate + '"), ' + '"SELECT Col1, Col2 LABEL Col1 \'Date\', Col2 \'Price\' FORMAT Col1 \'DD.MM.YYYY\', Col2 \'0.00\'", 1)'` might be high.
  2. `getRange` and `setValue` are used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. [Ref (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, from your showing script, the date object is converted as "UTC".

```js
function fetchHistoricalPrices(ticker) {
  var originalTicker = ticker;
  ticker = _ticker(ticker); // format to be understood by Google

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("stockData");
  var tempSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("temp");

  try {
    var [header, ...v1] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var dates = v1.map(([a]) => Utilities.formatDate(a, "UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd"));
    var formulas = dates.flatMap(date => ['=QUERY(googlefinance("' + ticker + '", "close", "' + date + '"), ' + '"SELECT Col1, Col2 FORMAT Col2 \'0.00\'", 1)', null]);
    log("Data retrieval and writing to temp completed for ticker " + originalTicker);
    tempSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, formulas.length).setFormulas([formulas]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var [, ...tempValues] = tempSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var res = [...Array(Math.ceil(tempValues[0].length / 2))].map((_) => [tempValues[0].splice(0, 2)[1] || "NA"]);
    var idx = header.indexOf(originalTicker);
    if (idx == -1) {
      sheet.getRange(1, sheet.getLastColumn() + 1, res.length + 1).setValues([[originalTicker], ...res]);
    } else {
      sheet.getRange(2, idx + 1, res.length).setValues(res);
    }
    log("Data written to stockData for ticker " + originalTicker);
    tempSheet.clear();
  } catch (error) {
    log("Error fetching data for ticker " + originalTicker + ": " + error);
  }
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, from your showing table, the cell values of column "A" are used as the date.

```js
function fetchHistoricalPrices(ticker) {
  var originalTicker = ticker;
  ticker = _ticker(ticker); // format to be understood by Google

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("stockData");
  var tempSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("temp");

  try {
    var [header, ...v1] = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
    var dates = v1.map(([a]) => a);
    var formulas = dates.flatMap(date => ['=QUERY(googlefinance("' + ticker + '", "close", "' + date + '"), ' + '"SELECT Col1, Col2 FORMAT Col2 \'0.00\'", 1)', null]);
    log("Data retrieval and writing to temp completed for ticker " + originalTicker);
    tempSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, formulas.length).setFormulas([formulas]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var [, ...tempValues] = tempSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var res = [...Array(Math.ceil(tempValues[0].length / 2))].map((_) => [tempValues[0].splice(0, 2)[1] || "NA"]);
    var idx = header.indexOf(originalTicker);
    if (idx == -1) {
      sheet.getRange(1, sheet.getLastColumn() + 1, res.length + 1).setValues([[originalTicker], ...res]);
    } else {
      sheet.getRange(2, idx + 1, res.length).setValues(res);
    }
    log("Data written to stockData for ticker " + originalTicker);
    tempSheet.clear();
  } catch (error) {
    log("Error fetching data for ticker " + originalTicker + ": " + error);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation. So, when this modified script was not useful for your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for testing the script? By this, I would like to confirm it.